# printf does not return anything on the screen

Tags: printf

I`m having problems on programing eith C language. I compiled a program that scan for open ports on a IP given by the user, and it has to show in the screen when the port is open. The problem is, it doesnt print anything! The program runs but nothing is shown in the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>          // printf(), perror()
#include <sys/types.h>      // AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
#include <sys/socket.h>     // socket(), connect()
#include <arpa/inet.h>      // htons(), inet_addr()
#include <unistd.h>         // close()

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int meusocket;
    int conecta;

    int port;
    int inicio = 0;
    int final = 65535;
    char * destino;
    destino = argv[1];

    struct sockaddr_in alvo;

    if(argv[1] == "")
    {
        printf("Informe o IP de acordo com o exemplo: \n");
        printf("./portscan 192.168.100.1");
        close(meusocket);
        return 0;
    }else{

    for(port=inicio;port<final;port++)
    {

    meusocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        alvo.sin_family = AF_INET;
        alvo.sin_port = htons(port);
        alvo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(destino);

        conecta = connect(meusocket, (struct sockaddr *)&alvo, sizeof alvo);

        if(conecta == 0)
        {
            printf("Porta %i [ABERTA] \n",port);
            close(meusocket);
            return 0;
        }else{
            close(meusocket);
            return 0;
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `argv[1] != ""` and `conecta != 0`. Where else do you have a `printf` in this code? Did you mean `if (conecta)` instead of `if(conecta == 0)`?

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem

Comment: Now it's stopping in the first `if` , even when I inform the IP, the return is the first `if`

Comment: I guess, you are not passing the command line argument. Aside: `Change if(argv[1] == "")` to `if (argc != 2 && argv[1] == "")`

Comment: I give up, each time a new problem appears. I'm really thankfull for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, I would have helped you if I knew the libraries you are using. You should probably get more help if you tag your question appropriately.